# navbar-fixed-top - page flickers and I am forced to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3, `navbar-fixed-top` class in particular. I have two menus that I fix to top with JQ as shown below. I see a weird bug only on short pages - only when the page height is *almost exactly as long as page content*: when I try to scroll, the page flickers and I am forced back to top. This happens with hand scroll or by using the scroll wheel. As a result, I can never see the last copyright line. [See video of this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16876271/jump-scroll.mov).

EDITED:
When I remove this line `$('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');` the issue goes away (but obviously I need that line). How do I fix this?

Also, when class `navbar-fixed-top` is applied to nav, the scroll happens smoothly (hence, I don't see the bug on long pages). When it's not applied - the bug comes back.

```js
var navFixStart;
var subFixStart;
var xs = 480;
var lg = 1200;
var mobileStart = (992 - 15);

if ($('body').hasClass('min')) {
  navFixStart = 40;
  subFixStart = 40;
} else {
  navFixStart = 0;
  subFixStart = 160;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < mobileStart) {
      // stuff
    } else {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > navFixStart) {
        $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');      // problem line
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() < mobileStart) {
      //mobile stuff
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('navbar-inverse').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('nav>div').removeClass("container-fluid").addClass("container");
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > navFixStart) {
        $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Nav */

nav {
  border: none !important;
  padding-top: 15px;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  -o-transition: 0.3s all ease;
  transition: 0.3s all ease;
}
nav div>ul>li>a:link {
  padding: 20px;
}
nav.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: rgba(244, 242, 239, 0.95);
}
nav.navbar-fixed-top.shad-bottom,
.subnav {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.navbar-brand {
  width: 145px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  width: 115px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand>img {
  height: auto;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 9px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 20px;
}
nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border: 0;
}
nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:link {
  line-height: 32px;
}
nav .navbar-collapse {
  padding: 0;
}
nav .navbar-collapse.collapsing,
nav .navbar-collapse.in {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-collapse .nav {
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse .nav {
  position: static;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="top" ontouchstart="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default shad-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Option</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Option</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Option</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Option</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Option</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Option</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Support</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="no-pad">
          <h1><a href="">Support</a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->

  <div class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet blandit lectus, quis auctor ante posuere sit amet. Fusce venenatis, arcu non viverra pulvinar, augue metus laoreet leo, sed convallis orci nisi vitae turpis. Cras sed euismod
            ligula. Sed id nulla elit. Aenean dapibus condimentum ex nec fermentum. Aliquam accumsan velit in dui sagittis cursus. Vestibulum id scelerisque risus, at efficitur turpis.
            <p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

      </div>
      <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->

  <div class="container-fluid block block-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquet blandit lectus, quis auctor ante posuere sit amet. Fusce venenatis, arcu non viverra pulvinar, augue metus laoreet leo, sed convallis orci nisi vitae turpis. Cras sed euismod
            ligula. Sed id nulla elit. Aenean dapibus condimentum ex nec fermentum. Aliquam accumsan velit in dui sagittis cursus. Vestibulum id scelerisque risus, at efficitur turpis.
            <p>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

      </div>
      <!-- end row -->

    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->

  <div class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="container no-pad">
      <footer class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center visible-xs" style="background-color:#45555f;">
          <div class="to-top"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>back to top</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center visible-xs">
          <div class="pad-bottom-md pad-top-sm"><a href="#">Products</a> | <a href="#">Services</a> | <a href="#">News</a> | <a href="#">Jobs</a> | <a href="#">Company</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end col -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h6>Company Name</h6>
          <address>
            Address 1<br>
            Address 2<br>
            Address 3<br>
            <span>555-555-5555</span>
            </address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pad-bottom-md">
          <h6>Connect</h6>
          <div class="social"> <a href="" class="twitter"><span class="mu-icon-twitter"></span></a>  <a href="" class="linkedin"><span class="mu-icon-linkedin2"></span></a>  <a href="" class="youtube"><span class="mu-icon-youtube"></span></a> 
          </div>
          <!-- end social -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 pad-bottom-md">
          <div class="copy">&copy; 2016 Company Name, LLC. <span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a> | <a href="terms.html">Terms</a> | <a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script-prototype-only.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
        if ($(window).width() < mobileStart) {                      
            $('.subnav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top'); 
        } else {                                                        
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > navFixStart) {
                $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > subFixStart) {
                    $('.subnav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top'); // bugger!!!
                } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= subFixStart) {
                    $('.subnav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                }
            } else {                                        
                // some more stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: The problem is that when your `subnav` is fixed the height of that `subnav` is 0 in the document (because it is fixed positioned) and if it is not fixed actual height is something about 50px. This causes flickering.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying if I add a height to .subnav it will fix it? Just tried `.subnav {height:50px;}` - still pulls me back up on scroll...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid block">
```

You have to add `padding-top` to this `div` equal to the height of your `subnav` element when the `subnav` is fixed.

For example if your `subnav` has 50px height your code may look like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < mobileStart) {
        $('.subnav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navFixStart) {
            $('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > subFixStart) {
                $('.subnav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                $('.container-fluid.block').css('padding-top', '50px');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= subFixStart) {
                $('.subnav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
                $('.container-fluid.block').css('padding-top', '0');
            }
        } else {
            // some more stuff
        }
    }
});
```

If your block with form already has padding-top (for example `20px`) you have to add `50px` to it (so in javascript change `50px` to `70px` and `0` to `20px`)

Comment: I spoke too soon. It is not solved. I included HTML for a simpler page - that has only one sticky nav instead of two. The problem line is `$('nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');`. When the screen height is just below the phone number on the footer, I am unable to scroll up. When the screen size is smaller or bigger - no issue at all.

Comment: Also, on a given page, there might be multiple blocks (containers) - content editors are entering them via CMS, so I can't can't control them. Each block has .block {padding: 40px 0;}